# Is there a way to count how many cell with a certain value are above a certain cell in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

So I have a list here of whatever that are ranked 1-40th. Only those that were top30th in the previous ranking will have a letter designation. jan-20 column shows the previous top30th having the letter designation, meaning that rank 14, 17 and 22 are new top30th members.

However, for new members of the top30th to be accepted officially, they need to be inside the top25 as a new comer (in this example all new comers are within that top25, hence the 'new' tag). And doing so will bump the lowest of the previous top 30th out of the qualification. If the new comer failed to reach the top25, it won't get accepted to the top30th list and won't get a letter designation unless there's a previous top30th member that fell below 35th. If this happens, the new comer will be accepted even if it failed to reach top25 the first time.

Now my issue is that I can't translate this to excel. As you can see, rank 31 and 33 (previous top30th members due to having letter designation) shouldn't be qualified this year as they got bumped off by the new comers rank 14 and 17. While rank 36 naturally got disqualified due to falling below 35th but even if it didn't fall below 35th, it will still get bumped off by rank 22 anyway. I'm having trouble telling the column that if it already has 30 total 'new' + 'old' values, everything should then be 'not qualified' already.

Here's what I have so far for that column:

`=IF(IF(C3<>"",IF(B3<31,"old",IF(B3>35,"","old")),IF(B3<26,"new",""))="","not qualified",IF(C3<>"",IF(B3<31,"old",IF(B3>35,"","old")),IF(B3<26,"new","")))`

column B = rank

column C = Jan-20

column D = Jan-22

Any ideas? Also, if there's another approach for my problem then I'm all ears. I'll be using it to a much larger data set for multiple sheets so I wanted to automate it. Previously they were doing it manually and it gets very tedious

[image: My table]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to do the desired output by using 2 more extra columns. I would prefer just to use 1 but excel won't allow a cell with a function that refer to itself indirectly. Anyway, the previous column (Jan-22) became my placeholder column now with the same formula, then I added a new column "Top30 count" which counts the "new" + "old" entries from my old Jan-22 column. Then I created a new Jan-22 column and it simply checks if the "Top30 count" column is less than 30 and if yes, just copy the value from the old "Jan-22" column, but if not, then it outputs the "not qualified" value.

It ain't that clean but it does the job. I'll just simply hide those 2 columns. But if you have another approach to my problem, feel free to add.